# Oracle Java Tutorial [Essential Classes > Basic I/O > File Operations] and java.nio.file.Files class javadocs Discrepancy

Tags: java

I am reading Oracle's Java tutorials, specifically the Web page entitled **File Operations** which is part of the **Basic I/O** lesson in the **Essential Classes** trail.

According to the section entitled [What *Is* a Glob?](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html#glob)

> Two methods in the `Files` class accept a glob argument, but what is a *glob*?

In the *javadoc* for class `java.nio.file.Files`, I only found one method, namely: [newDirectoryStream(Path,String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-)

Is there really a discrepancy between Oracle's Java tutorials and the *javadoc* for class `java.nio.file.Files`, or am I missing something?

Comment: I'd say you are correct, and this is an actual inconsistency - including all versions up to Java 14: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html

Comment: Counting is hard. Off by one bugs are the [#0 bug](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51Bi6Vl%2B7yL._AC_.jpg)!

Comment: It's not a great way to write the documentation anyway. Instead of saying "there are two", saying which one(s) would be better.

Comment: Or maybe just saying "some methods" and leave it at that.  Stale documentation is a terrible thing.  (I also only found one method.)